# iis only Add Expires headers to images

Tags: iis

Add expires headers in iis is very Easy,but this cache all the static files. now i want only 
add expires headers to images,how can i do that? even i want cached specific file?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. put all your images in one folder
2. enter the manager--> yoursite--> images folder (or specific file)
3. right click--> HTTP HEADERs--> Set expire header/date !  --> APPLY/OK

Comment: Ta for that. I used this to configure different expires for different folders in the app. Only thing that works on IIS7. Also for IIS6 you can achieve the same with some metabase magic - http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2008/07/07/overriding-iis6-wildcard-maps-on-individual-directories/

Comment: Depending on the version of IIS, step 3 might be: double-click "Http Response Headers" --> click Add... --> Enter Expires in name and a future data (15 Apr 2020 20:00:00 GMT) in value --> OK

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching for a simpler solution and I found this.

Keep your static content inside a folder (eg: css, js). Create a `web.config` file inside that folder. Add these following lines. Here `7` is the number of days, change it as you desire.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="7.00:00:00" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

You are free to keep as many static content folder as you want, simply add this `web.config` file. Hope this helps.